# Create 3 new columns based off of transaction period (year, month, max year)

Tags: sql-server

Column `[TRAN_YRNO]` contains month/year data in the format YYYYMM (ex. `202304`). I am trying to split this into two columns, one for month and one for year. I then want to create a third column that contains the max year. (should be 2023 for all rows)

```sql
SELECT 
       [TNET]
      ,[SORTCODE]    
      ,[LOADDATE]
      ,[TRAN_YRMO]
  FROM [dbo].[tbl_941_Monthly_Cumulative]
```

```sql
SELECT c.*, c.[year]
from  c
LEFT JOIN b
ON c.[year] = b.[Max Year]

(SELECT
*,
LEFT([TRAN_YRMO],4) as 'Year' ,
RIGHT([TRAN_YRMO],2) as 'Month'
FROM [dbo].[tbl_941_Monthly_Cumulative])c

(SELECT
MAX(a.[year]) AS 'Max Year'

from 

(SELECT *,
LEFT([TRAN_YRMO],4) as 'Year' ,
RIGHT([TRAN_YRMO],2) as 'Month'
FROM [dbo].[tbl_941_Monthly_Cumulative])a)b
```

Here is what I have tried so far, which obviously errors out.

The goal is to have something that looks like:

| TNET | SORTCODE | LOADDATE | TRAN_YRMO | YEAR | MONTH | MAX YEAR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  | 202304 | 2023 | 04 | 2023 |
|  |  |  | 202301 | 2023 | 01 | 2023 |
|  |  |  | 202208 | 2022 | 08 | 2023 |
|  |  |  | 202107 | 2021 | 07 | 2023 |

Answer (score 1):

Just another approach using the window function `max() over()` and a `Cross Apply` to calculate the expressions once

Optional: wrap the left/right in a convert(int,...)

```
Select A.*
      ,B.Year
      ,B.Month
      ,MaxYear = max(B.Year) over()
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values ( left([TRAN_YRMO],4),right([TRAN_YRMO],2) ) )B(Year,Month)
```

Comment: I tried adding that to the query and got hit with this message. Any suggestions?              
 Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near 'c'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 21
Incorrect syntax near 'b'.

Comment: @JacobKaczmarek The query is valid.   https://dbfiddle.uk/4ZpX2UvL   The point was to introduce the window functions and the Cross Apply.